# How to join 2 columns from the same table

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 column in a table "userID" and "manager". Each userID has a manager, and each manager is listed in userID column and has a manager itself.

How can I create a new column called "skip_manager" and for each userID's manager to get his manager?

```
Select
    employee_id as ID,
    login_name as userID,
    employee_name as Name,
    department_id as BU,
    supervisor_login_name as manager,
    business_title as title,
    hire_date,
    is_active_record,
    effective_start_day,
    effective_end_day,
    is_employed,
    job_title

From 
BOOKER.D_EMPLOYEE_HISTORY

Where
department_id in (5404,5406,5405,5412,5452,4345,4366)
```

I need to add a column named skip_manager where to export the manager's manager near the column manager.

Export ex:

```
id        userid    name    bu  manager
1031    xxxxche Lxxxxxan 5406   sxxxxb
1032    xxxxarc Bxxxxxxan 5406  paxxxxxa
1006    xxxxpem Mxxxxxru 5406   ixxxxar
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images). And take a look at [mcve] too.

Comment: I have tried  
SELECT T1.*,(select manager from BOOKER.D_EMPLOYEE_HISTORY where T1.manager = c.userID) 'skip_manager_Id'
FROM BOOKER.D_EMPLOYEE_HISTORY T1
JOIN BOOKER.D_EMPLOYEE_HISTORY T2 ON T2.userID = T1.manager */

but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

check this -

```
create table EMP_TABLE
(
    UserId int,
    ManagerId int,
    FirstName varchar(20)
)

insert into EMP_TABLE
select 1, 2, 'Ajit' union
select 2, 3, 'Amar' union
select 3, 4, 'Kiran' union
select 4, 1, 'Vishal' union
select 5, 2, 'Ram' 

select * from EMP_TABLE

SELECT T1.*,(select ManagerId from EMP_TABLE c where T1.ManagerId = c.UserId) 'skip_manager_Id'
FROM EMP_TABLE T1
JOIN EMP_TABLE T2 ON T2.userID = T1.ManagerId
```

Comment: The requested data is not in EDX.

Comment: Above solution is just sample with test data showing to get manager's manger id (skip_manager_id). you need to use that logic and get your job done.

Answer (score -1):

This technique is called self join. You can join the 2 instances of the same table.

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP_TABLE T1
JOIN EMP_TABLE T2 ON T2.userID = T1.manager
<WHERE CONDITION>
```

Comment: I need to return a column named skip_manager beside the other columns